# Is ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND supposed to work in Redstone 4?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, uwp, win32gui

I'm using ACCENT_ENABLE_ACRYLICBLURBEHIND in my WPF app. I have Redstone 4 at work, but Redstone 5 at home. Obviously Redstone 4 does Acrylic on the calendar & start menu, etc... but the API doesn't seem to work well in RS4. Very flashy and layers upon itself until its solid black. Do I need to do something different on RS4? The calendar and start menu don't have the problem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://withinrafael.com/2018/02/01/adding-acrylic-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps-redstone-4-desktop-apps/) will help?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra -- Hmm... seems like on RS4, it requires you to have AllowTransparency=True where on RS5 it doesn't. Because of that, you can't really use it with WindowChrome. Oh well. Guess its RS5+ then. If you don't have AllowTransparency=True, you get the weird flashing.

Comment: Supposed to work is hard to define when you are talking about unsupported and undocumented parameters.